# Converting a publickey mod & publickey exponent to an RSA key in C#

Tags: c#

I've got a very long string (512 chars) that is the mod for the RSA key. I have tried converting it to an int, however it throws an overflow exception all the time:

```
int mod = Int32.Parse(loginData["publickey_mod"], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

I have also got an exponent in the form of a string (eg `"010001"`). I have been trying to generate an RSA but the overflow error is bugging me. How can I makse sure that I don't get an overflow error and additionally, how do I construct the RSA of this data in C#?

Comment: you could use a `BigInteger`, but what are you planning to do with it? Most of the .net encryption libraries deal with byte arrays.

Comment: For some reason system.numerics is not recognised

Comment: what version and flavor of the framework are you targetting?

Comment: I'm using .NET framework 4.5

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. Adding a reference was necessary for it to work.